# Search for specific words in cells, add true or false if even one is present

Tags: excel, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

So I've googled the internet, but can't seem to find a proper function.

I have cells containing some Categories and in each cell, they're different.

Example:

1. Art, History
2. Architecture, Design, Art, Magic
3. Photography, Design

What I'm after is this, that if a cell contains even one word from a specific list, then it would add a true or false next to another cell.

I know there's a function to find a specific word from a cell and then true or false it:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Art";K3));"true";"false")
```

And I also found something that I need, but this doesn't seem to be working in **openOffice**:

```
=IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"Architecture","Magazines","Movie","Music","Photography","Theory"},K2)),"true","false")
```

How can this be done?

Comment: OpenOffice Calc would be great for now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second formula will work also in Excel only as array formula. So even in openoffice an array formula is needed.

The formula is:

```
{=IF(SUM(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH({"Architecture","Magazines","Movie","Music","Photography","Theory"},K2))))>0,"true","false")}
```

To enter an array formula in openoffice, enter the formula first and click **fx** then. In the Function Wizard dialog check the [x] Array checkbox.
[image]

If you fill array formulas downwards with the cell handle, then you will create a range array. This is not the goal in this case. Thats why do not fill with the cell handle. Copy the formula and paste it into the other cells.

[image]

Comment: Hmm… wierd, I'm getting a Error 501 with this formula, did everything as you've very well explained in your reply.

Comment: Maybe your formula separator is not comma, but semicolon? Try =IF(SUM(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH({"Architecture";"Magazines";"Movie";"Music";"Photography";"Theory"};K2))))>0;"true";"false")